# C++ class in separate file not compiling. Already defined in Class.obj one or more multiply defined symbols found

Tags: c++, file, class, oop, compiler-errors

So I've done extensive googling and searching on StackOverflow and am unable to find a solution despite several answers with this exact issue.

I am trying to create a test class in an external file called `Fpc5.cpp`

It's contents are:

`Fpc5.cpp`

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Fpc5.h";
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

class Fpc5 {
    int bar;
public:
    void testMethod();
};

void Fpc5::testMethod() {
    cout << "Hey it worked! ";
}
```

and my main .cpp file:

`Test.cpp`

```
// Test.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "iostream"
//#include "Fpc5.cpp"
#include "Fpc5.h";
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello" << endl;
    Fpc5 testObj;
    testObj.testMethod();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

all the answers I've read indicate this is caused becaused I used to be including the class in the main file itself which is why I created a header file

`Fpc5.h`

```
#pragma once
void testMethod();
```

This changed the error, but still did not fix the issue. Currently my `Test.cpp` does not recognize a Fpc5 class. I've also tried adding the `Fpc5.cpp` and `Fpc5.h` in `stdafx.h` and that still does not resolve the issue.

`stdafx.h`

```
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently
//

#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here

//#include "Fpc5.cpp"
#include "Fpc5.h"
```

I'm sure this a simple syntax/conceptual understanding error, but I'm quite new to c++ and am not sure what is wrong.

Comment: Your class definition needs to be in the header, not the source file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definition of your class and it must be in Fpc5.h

```
class Fpc5 {
    int bar;
public:
    void testMethod();
};
```

Then, you have Fpc5.cpp where you implement methods of the class:

```
#include "Fpc5.h" // Compiler needs class definition to compile this file!

void Fpc5::testMethod()
{
}
```

And then you can use Fpc5 class in Test.cpp

```
#include "Fpc5.h"

int main()
{
    Fpc5 foo;
    foo.testMethod();
    return 0;
}
```

As an alternative you can pack everything into Test.cpp

Comment: This does allow my Test.cpp to recognize an Fpc5 object, but now when I try to compile I get 2 errors: "unresolved external symbol [...] referenced in function_main" and "1 unresolved externals" any idea on those?

Comment: I just needed to clean and rebuild my solution. Thanks for the quick answer.

Answer (score 1):

Move the definition of your class:

```
class Fpc5 {
    int bar;
public:
    void testMethod();
};
```

to the header file, "Fpc5.h".

Implement the methods to "Fpc5.cpp".